# Cannot Enable Firebase Authentication in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-console

When trying to enable either the Google sign-in method, or the regular email/password methods, I get an error, something along the lines of "Unknown error encountered". For Google Auth, it says "CREDENTIALS MISSING" in the JSON response, while for Email/Password it says "INVALID_ARGUMENT".

I have tried deleting the project and starting a new one, but the same error persists. I'll include some snippets from the console log below, any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: I can apparently update these settings in Firefox without a problem? I'm not sure what's going on here, but I guess if others have this problem, I would try a different browser?

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbrk7.png)
[Expanded JSON Response Google Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCTA.png)

Comment: Thank you for your update. It was driving me crazy. I think I have had enough with Chrome browser. Its full of errors!! I have been literally pulling out my hair trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

Is it saying 'Error enabling ...'?
Check if only the native providers are not being enabled and the others such as Google sign in is working or not.
For me switching browsers didn't work(Might have worked if I switched to third browser). 
If that's the case, check if there is any CORS extension in your browser enabled. It blocks some of the requests. I deleted that and it worked.